# How to deal with slash character in java

Tags: java

I have a string that contains file path like

```
String str = C:\Users\dob\Downloads\marking_scheme.doc
```

I want to split it using split("") method like

```
 String arr[] = str.split("\");
```

But for some reason this method is mot working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: that's because a \ is a special character in a String. try \\ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, the `\` is a special character which needs to be escaped, thus in your case, `\` would need to become `\\`.

However, since the `split` method takes a string which represents a regular expression, and in regular expression language the `\` on its own is special as well, you will need to escape it one more time, thus, you would need to use `\\\\`, like so:

```
String str = "C:\\Users\\dob\\Downloads\\marking_scheme.doc";
        for(String s : str.split("\\\\"))
            System.out.println(s);
```

Yields:

```
C:
Users
dob
Downloads
marking_scheme.doc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 String str="C:\\Users\\dob\\Downloads\\marking_scheme.doc";
 String arr[] = str.split("\\\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape "\" character, so use:

```
String str = C:\\Users\\dob\\Downloads\\marking_scheme.doc

 String arr[] = str.split("\\\\");
```

Comment: This will throw an exception. The `\\` will need to be escaped twice for regular expression arguments.

Comment: By default the path is C:\Users\dob\Downloads\marking_scheme.doc. Because thats the path the user somehow inputs

Comment: Sorry, just added response with no checking, fixed